# oracle Query to select last updated record in a group for set of records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle table as below

```
OrderName      StartDate   EndDate     Lastupdate
--------------------------------------------------
Ord-100-A1     01-Jan-20   01-Feb-20   02-Mar-20
Ord-100-A2     05-Mar-20   05-Apr-20   03-Apr-20
Ord-200-A1     10-Apr-20   10-May-20   04-May-20
Ord-200-A2     15-May-20   15-Jun-20   05-Jun-20
Ord-300-A1     20-Jun-20   20-Jul-20   06-Jul-20
Ord-300-A2     25-Jul-20   25-Aug-20   07-Aug-20
```

On any column change (start and end date), the `Lastupdate` and the `ordername` columns will change.

The user will pass the order number to get the latest ordername, start and end date for the order,

I need the query result as below (if the user pass 100,200 and 300)

```
OrderName      StartDate   EndDate     
-------------------------------------
Ord-100-A2     05-Mar-20   05-Apr-20 
Ord-200-A2     15-May-20   15-Jun-20
Ord-300-A2     25-Jul-20   25-Aug-20
```

I am using the below query but not able to fetch the last updated record for each order group, what needs to be framed in subquery:

```
Select 
    OrderName, startDate, EndDate 
from 
    orders 
where 
    substr(ordername, 5, 3) in ('100', '200', '300') 
group by 
    OrderName, startDate, EndDate 
order by 
    lastupdate desc
```

Comment: Reverting to the original question.  This site does not work this way, where you keep changing the question based on further requirements.

Comment: I have posted the fiddle code to understand my requirement, I am not sure how to update the demo fiddle

Comment: Paste the Fiddle link here along with a clear statement of the problem and I can take a look.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6ec77155eac61bf0b1bf5177f61de53c

for some of the records ordername will be different and the lastupdate is same. how to get the latest ordername. If I query through order by lastupdate desc I am getting the ordername as ord-100-A3 for the 100 records but with your query it is showing as 'ord-100-A2'

Comment: I think I see the edge case.  If a given order number happens to have a _tie_ for two or more records, for the most recent last update time, and you want to see _both_ (or more) of those records, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`.  That's it.

Comment: I need only one record not 2 or more. I replaced with Rank() it is giving 2 records is there any way to get one record for 100 order

Comment: Yes, you may add a second term to the `ORDER BY` clause in `ROW_NUMBER` which would break the tie.  What you choose is really up to you.

Comment: Can you please update in the fiddle, I got bit confused
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7277096baadb0eed28c200b6501151d9

Comment: For example, if you wanted to break the tie by choosing the record with the more recent start date, you could [see this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b7436e664ea6076eb957a536c52d0544).

Comment: Thank you Tim. your response is great. I will consider the table change also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can handle this requirement with some regex support:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT o.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(OrderName, '^Ord-\d+')
                                   ORDER BY Lastupdate DESC) rn
    FROM orders o
)

SELECT OrderName, StartDate, EndDate
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

If you just wanted to restrict to e.g. orders 200 and 300, you could also add a `WHERE` clause with `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(OrderName, '^Ord-(200|300)-')
```

However, at this point I would comment that if you need to use regex this heavily for such a simple requirement, you might want to reconsider your table design.  Instead, you might want to maintain a separate column for a dedicated order name, which would make writing the query much easier, faster, and would eliminate the need to use regular expressions in this way.

Comment: Thank you Tim, The above query going to do regular expression for entire table.. How to fetch only for 100 and 200 order or 100 and 300 order

Comment: See the updated answer, and also maybe consider changing your table design.

Comment: I have ordername change for the same lastupdate date but the ordername sequence getting changed Can you please address this scenario

Comment: I don't understand your scenario, so unfortunately I can't address it.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle code in the problem description